# how to call client_secrets.json in youtube api?

Tags: java, json, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get a youtube video comments through youtube API on my dynamic web-app project.

My code:

```
private static int counter = 0;
private static YouTube youtube;

public static void getYoutubeOauth() throws Exception {
    List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl");

    Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "commentthreads");
    youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();

    String videoId = "KIgxmV9xXBQ";

    // Get video comments threads
    CommentThreadListResponse commentsPage = prepareListRequest(videoId).execute();

    while (true) {
        handleCommentsThreads(commentsPage.getItems());

        String nextPageToken = commentsPage.getNextPageToken();
        if (nextPageToken == null)
            break;

        // Get next page of video comments threads
        commentsPage = prepareListRequest(videoId).setPageToken(nextPageToken).execute();
    }

    System.out.println("Total: " + counter);
}

private static YouTube.CommentThreads.List prepareListRequest(String videoId) throws Exception {

    return youtube.commentThreads()
                  .list("snippet,replies")
                  .setVideoId(videoId)
                  .setMaxResults(100L)
                  .setModerationStatus("published")
                  .setTextFormat("plainText");
}

private static void handleCommentsThreads(List<CommentThread> commentThreads) {

    for (CommentThread commentThread : commentThreads) {
        List<Comment> comments = Lists.newArrayList();
        comments.add(commentThread.getSnippet().getTopLevelComment());

        CommentThreadReplies replies = commentThread.getReplies();
        if (replies != null)
            comments.addAll(replies.getComments());

        System.out.println("Found " + comments.size() + " comments.");

        // Do your comments logic here
        counter += comments.size();
    }
}
```

while executing above code I'm getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` at line `Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "commentthreads");`

FYI: I do Know what `NullPointerException` is. i.e `string n = null; if(n=="h");` causes for `NullPointerException`

I would expect the cause to be countered by `client_secrets.json` file, because I don't know where to place and how to call it in my code.

My current `client_secrets.json` is placed under `/home/UserName/workspace/RemoteSystemsTempFiles/Duck/WebContent/WEB-INF/client_secrets.json`

Comment: maybe scopes is null. did you try guard this variable?

Comment: @TalAvissar "Guard this variable"? what do you mean & and plz read bellow answer comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the client secrets json file as follows:

```
// Load client secrets.
Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(Auth.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json"));
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, clientSecretReader);
```

For more information on how to use Auth with google API take a look [here](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java)

Comment: thx for ur reply, I am using dynamic web-app and i am trying to implement his on a servlet so, in my case i suppose i can't add an external .json file to my project `java resources`, can u show me reading client_secrets.json from an external directory I tried adding `Auth.class.getResourceAsStream("/home/hazrat/Documents/eclipse-jee-neon-3-linux-gtk-x86_64/eclipse/client_secrets.json")` but it says null pointerexception althou i can access this exact location through my terminal. and If u dont mind plz explain a little what is `list<String> scope ` for and what to put?